# iOS 12.1.4 : Lost keychain passwords after signing out from Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud, password, keychain

I have an iPhone 7 running iOS 12.1.4. Today, I just randomly signed out from my Apple ID. Then I again signed in using my Apple ID and received all my pictures and videos back from iCloud. But I lost all my **Website & App Passwords** (Settings → Passwords & Accounts → Website & App Passwords).

I had many website and app passwords stored which are now lost.

I tried iCloud and iTunes software on Windows, but didn’t find anything. My phone is regularly backed up on iCloud (Automatic backup from iPhone).

I also tried turning on and off **Keychain** under iCloud, and again signed out and in; but to no avail.

Is there anyway I can get back all my Safari website and app passwords back? Note that, I do not have a Mac.